# Is it bad practice to put DOM Node objects in your app state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm implementing a store/state pattern in my plain JS project as it exists in Vue and I have some DOM elements that the various controllers (MVC model) need to access.

Is it a good idea to put them in the `state` object, inside `state.runtime` for example? As I understand, the `state` object must be plain JS object, and shouldn't contain functions or class instances (DOM Nodes), but I can't think of a better place to put those objects, because they need to be shared across multiple scripts.

Comment: Well you can't serialise them, so yes I'd say it's a bad practice. The state should be your model only, the DOM elements pertain to the view. Can you give an example of what you're doing with them?

Comment: You should probably try to manage that scenario with refs. I must be honest, in the past I happened to save DOM nodes in state, since I needed to be noticed when a certain node did mount in a scenario with a lot of animations, it worked fine since, until the DOM node is mounted it does not change reference, hence it does not trigger a rendering loop. But that's the only scenario where you can think of saving a non serializable object at state. Do your controllers need to be noticed in the very same exact moment the node mounts/unmounts? If the answer is no, you're good to go with `refs`.

Comment: @Bergi Usage example - the main class creates some HTML elements and the controllers need to access them, for example to get width/height, etc. Since I'm already using a store in those controllers, I would like to make them dumber by not keeping a reference to the script that created them, and just have them do their own thing.

Comment: Also the DOM nodes don't need to persist, that's why I'm putting them in a property called "runtime".

Comment: @CesarePolonara Can you show me an example how you implement refs in plain JS? I'm not sure if it's the same thing as refs in Vue.

Comment: Are you implementing some sort  of observable pattern on those nodes, like proxies? How do controllers know if some nodes exist or not when they try to access them ?

Comment: A ref is a basic pattern, just an object with `value` property, so a value could be passed by *reference*, as objects do in JS. Refs are reactive in Vue but it won't matter in vanilla JS, unless you want to reimplement the whole reactivity. It's unclear what scenario you describe. This could be XY problem. Consider providing more info and code, so it would be clear what a possible solution could look like.